# Converting MySQL query to CI syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem converting my MySQL query to codeigniter syntax.

This is my MySQL query.

```
Select id, name, code, status, question_count, session
from s3r_set  
left join 
 (Select set_id, count(id) as question_count
    from  s3r_question group by set_id) question 
on question.set_id = id
left join
 (SELECT session_id as session, set_id
    from s3r_session) s3rsession
on s3rsession.set_id = id
order by id
```

This is what I've got so far in CI:

```
$this->db->select('id, name, code, status, question_count, session');
$this->db->from('s3r_set');
$this->db->join('s3r_question', '(Select set_id, count(id) as question_count
                                from  s3r_question group by set_id) question
                                on question.set_id = id', 'left');
$this->db->join('s3r_session', '(SELECT session_id as session, set_id
                                from s3r_session) s3rsession
                                on s3rsession.set_id = id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('id', "desc");

$q = $this->db->get();

if($q->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $q->result();
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: so what's the problem? Error? or not the same result?

Comment: it just brakes in CI, I guess  it's because I've got nested select queries inside JOIN, but I've got no clue how to do it other way in CI.

Comment: nested joins/selects are ok, unless you are using `$this->db()` somewhere in previous 'instance' of `->db()->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one you are doing the `join` wrong:

```
$this->db->join('s3r_question', '(Select set_id, count(id) as question_count
                                from  s3r_question group by set_id) question
                                on question.set_id = id', 'left');
```

**Should be:**

```
$this->db->join('(Select set_id, count(id) as question_count 
from  s3r_question group by set_id) question', 'question.set_id = id');
```

**Refer to formatting here:**
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#join

The `...join(FROM_TABLE, ON WHAT VALUE TO JOIN ON, OPTIONAL > WHAT TYPE OF JOIN, LEFT/RIGHT/ETC;)`